# How to find the function of a surface

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric, solid-of-revolution

Let’s say we have $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ in range $\,x\in[0,5]\,$ and we revolved around the $x$-axis what would the function $z=z(x,y)$ of this new surface? How can I find this surface?

I have the volume of this surface:

$$\int_{0}^{5}\pi xdx = V$$

in 2D the rate of change of the area under the curve is $f(x)$ will this be the same in 2D with the volume, how can I find the equation $\,z=z(x,y)\,?$

I was trying:

$$A = \int\pi xdx$$
$$\frac{dA}{dx} = \pi x$$

Comment: SirMrpirateroberts, what do you want to get exactly? The equation of the surface or the value of its area?

Comment: @Angelo yes the equation of the surface area

Comment: SirMrpirateroberts, if you add to your post what you tried to solve the problem, I will help you, otherwise moderators will close your question.

Comment: @Angelo I tried taking the derivate of the Volume

Comment: I dont know where to start, people seem to be liking this question

Comment: You want something called a (elliptic) paraboloid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid

Comment: @SeanRoberson given the function which creates the paraboloid when it is revolved how to find the paraboloid that forms?

Comment: SirMrpirateroberts, the volume is a number, not a function, so it does not make sense to calculate its derivative. As I pointed out before, I will help you only if you add more context to your post and write explicitly all what you tried.

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Following the other comments given, please edit the original post with your tried instead of burying them in the comments.

Comment: @Angelo what if I take the derivate of $\int \pi x dx$

Comment: SirMrpirateroberts, if you take the derivative of $\int\pi x\mathrm dx$, you will not get the correct solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the equation of the surface, then read my answer.

A point $P(x,y,z)$ belongs to the surface if and only if the distance from $P$ to $x$-axis is equal to $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

$\mathrm{dist}(P,x\mathrm{-axis})=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\,.$

Consequently a point $P(x,y,z)$ belongs to the surface if and only if $\,\sqrt{y^2+z^2}=\sqrt x\;.$

Hence the equation of the surface is

$y^2+z^2=x\quad$ (in implicit form)

or

$z=\pm\sqrt{x-y^2}\quad$ (in explicit form).

But if you are interested in calculating the value of the area of the surface, you have to use the following formula:

$\mathrm{Area}=2\pi\displaystyle\int_0^5f(x)\sqrt{1+f’^2(x)}\,\mathrm dx\,.$

Comment: @Thank you.....

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts, you are welcome !

Comment: Is there any theorem like the one I am trying to find like taking the rate of change of volume of something like that to get a 3d function?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts, the equation of the surface obtained by rotating the graph of the function $y=f(x)$ around the $x$-axis is the following one: $\;\color{blue}{y^2+z^2=f^2(x)}\,.\;$